# How to use more than one asyncio websocket in same script?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, websocket, python-asyncio

I am using an older Python3 script with 3.6.x, i had a setup with two websockets which worked just fine.  now, with v3.7 i am stuck and can't make the 2nd websocket running anymore.  with v3.6 i used terms like @asyncio.coroutine, yield from and such which changed evidently and got a bit simpler in pyton v3.7 and websockets v8.1.  the two websockets use two distinct PORT number (51945,51946), the machine IP is 192.168.2.2.  OS was initially Slackware 14.2, though now i use Slackware-Current.

the 1st websocket server runs for ever and listens to websocket calls that originate from an HTML page via Firefox/Chrome and JavaScript or from a python websocket client.  here the script excerpts of the 1st websocket setup (which works just fine) :

```py
class fmDaemon( Daemon):
    def __init__( self, me):
        self.me = me
    def run( self):
        while True:
            async def coroutine_daemon_websocket_server( websocket, path):
                msg = await websocket.recv()
                if msg != None:
                    msg_out = "{}".format( msg)
                    await websocket.send( msg_out)
                    fmProcessor( self.me, msg)
            start_server = websockets.serve( coroutine_daemon_websocket_server, self.me.IP, self.me.PORT)
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( start_server)
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
            asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
```

```py
def fmWebsocketClientSend( me, msg):
    async def coroutine_websocket_client():
        async with websockets.connect( 'ws://{}:{}/'.format( me.IP, me.PORT)) as websocket:
            await websocket.send( msg)
            rcvd = await websocket.recv()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( coroutine_websocket_client())
```

JavaScript:

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
var ws;
function init() {
  // Connect to Web Socket
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://me.IP:me.PORT/");
  // Set event handlers.
  ws.onopen = function() {
    output("onopen ●");
  };
  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    // e.data contains received string.
    output("onmessage: " + e.data + " ●");
  };
  ws.onclose = function() {
    output("onclose ●");
  };
  ws.onerror = function(e) {
    output("onerror ●");
    console.log(e)
  };
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<A onclick='ws.send("save")'></A>
<A onclick='ws.send("quit")'></A>
etc etc...
```

the problem is now with the 2nd websocket setup that gives error messages and stops working.  this time the websocket calls originate from the same HTML page as before but from the HTML page overlay, and use a separate unique PORT number.  i tried many different implementations including while loops without success.  i am actually not even sure if i should call this construct a websocket server or client : i believe it will be the former.

```py
def fmOverlay( me):
    msg = None
    async def coroutine_overlay_websocket_server():
        nonlocal msg
        uri     = "ws://{}:{}".format( me.IP, me.PORT_overlay)
        async with websockets.connect( uri) as websocket:
            msg = await websocket.recv()
        return msg
    # nest_asyncio.apply()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( coroutine_overlay_websocket_server())
```

JavaScript:

```
function initOverlay() {
  // Connect to Web Socket
  ws_overlay = new WebSocket("ws://me.IP:me.PORT_overlay/");
  // Set event handlers.
  ws_overlay.onopen = function() {
    output("onopen ●");
  };
  ws_overlay.onmessage = function(e) {
    // e.data contains received string.
    output("onmessage: " + e.data + " ●");
  };
  ws_overlay.onclose = function() {
    output("onclose ●");
  };
  ws_overlay.onerror = function(e) {
    output("onerror ●");
    console.log(e)
  };
}
```

Here is an ERROR message :

```
2019-12-15 22:02:03 ERROR Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 191, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 1239, in coroutine_daemon_websocket_server
    fmProcessor( self.me, msg)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 6308, in fmProcessor
    fmUID( me, 'uid delete')
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 7388, in fmUID
    fmOverlay( me)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 6049, in fmOverlay
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( coroutine_overlay_websocket_server())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 566, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 521, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

```sh
lsof -i :51945 ; lsof -i :51946
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 10771  user    7u  IPv4 3781925      0t0  TCP machine.domain:51945 (LISTEN)
python3 10771  user    8u  IPv4 3783047      0t0  TCP machine.domain:51945->machine.domain:33600 (ESTABLISHED)
firefox 26954  user   76u  IPv4 3784898      0t0  TCP machine.domain:33600->machine.domain:51945 (ESTABLISHED)
```

If I included NEST_ASYNCIO then I get a slightly different ERROR message.

ERROR message with NEST_ASYNCION included :

```
2019-12-15 22:17:27 ERROR Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 191, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 1239, in coroutine_daemon_websocket_server
    fmProcessor( self.me, msg)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 6308, in fmProcessor
    fmUID( me, 'uid delete')
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 7388, in fmUID
    fmOverlay( me)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 6049, in fmOverlay
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( coroutine_overlay_websocket_server())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 251, in __step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/home/user/programs/bin/fm", line 6032, in coroutine_overlay_websocket_server
    async with websockets.connect( uri) as websocket:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 535, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 954, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 941, in create_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 464, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/futures.py", line 260, in __await__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 318, in __wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 494, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('192.168.2.2', 51946)
```

I am a bit lost here. I am also not an expert python coder.  I read a few months ago about people having similar problem after the python and websocket version change though i am not sure if the problem is in my code, and is it still a bug with python/websocket ?

Any feedback GREATLY appreciated - this problem goes on for months...

EDIT : i tried to adjust a bit the second websocket script as shown below but also that only revealed that there is conflict between the first and second  websockets' port numbers - see DEBUG below.

```
def fmOverlay( me):
    msg = None

    async def coroutine_overlay_websocket_server( websocket, path):
        nonlocal msg
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        return msg
    start_server = websockets.serve( coroutine_overlay_websocket_server, me.IP, me.PORT_overlay)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( start_server)
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
    print( msg)
```

here some DEBUG lines

```
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server < GET / HTTP/1.1
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server < Headers([('Host', '192.168.2.2:51945'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13'), ('Origin', 'null'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Key', 'AKzNavhcPOEO9pa6b/eS4A=='), ('Connection', 'keep-alive, Upgrade'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Upgrade', 'websocket')])
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server > HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server > Headers([('Upgrade', 'websocket'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', 'XfPueFTcxLKtK2cjLUN0ULPR2jg='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate'), ('Date', 'Fri, 20 Dec 2019 03:06:34 GMT'), ('Server', 'Python/3.7 websockets/8.1')])

2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server < GET / HTTP/1.1
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server < Headers([('Host', '192.168.2.2:51946'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13'), ('Origin', 'null'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Key', 'MXL9z2es6wDY09rgAFtYsA=='), ('Connection', 'keep-alive, Upgrade'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Upgrade', 'websocket')])
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server > HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
2019-12-19 22:06:34 DEBUG server > Headers([('Upgrade', 'websocket'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', 'wO27sdA/mtE1QyssG9hs4de9KV8='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate'), ('Date', 'Fri, 20 Dec 2019 03:06:34 GMT'), ('Server', 'Python/3.7 websockets/8.1')])
```

i must do something fundamentally wrong here, right ?  perhaps i should set up both two websockets at once at the beginning and keep them running as daemons ?   how can i keep them separated ?  as said earlier, this setup worked fine with python v3.6.6 and websockets v6.0...